# http_response_code() always returns 200, even on 404

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, http-response-codes

I'm trying to use Apache's `ErrorDocument` to handle client and server errors by passing them to `error.php`.

### `.htaccess`

```
ErrorDocument 400 /error.php
...
ErrorDocument 404 /error.php
...
ErrorDocument 511 /error.php
```

### `error.php`

```
var_dump(http_response_code());
```

So, I point my browser to `mywebsite.com/noeutdhoaeu`, which does not exist. The response from the server is `404 Not Found`, as you would expect. But PHP gives me `200`.

What gives?

**Edit**: I have this same exact code on my Apache-based localhost and it works just fine. That is the reason I am asking this question. PHP is completely aware that a 404 error has occurred in my local environment. On my hosted environment, however, PHP has no idea.

Comment: could you show us  your php code?

Comment: That's because PHP didn't set a response code. PHP can't know that it's parsing an ErrorDocument for Apache.

Comment: @KimAlexander That's all the code for that page.

Comment: @jreuab That seems strange to me, because the same exact code works perfectly on localhost.

Comment: @MarcusMcLean, well, if you're sure that it does work, maybe your host is using fastcgi and not the Apache PHP-SAPI.

Comment: @jreuab I had not considered that. Do you know if this is changeable via cPanel?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @Boaz said, PHP doesn't know what Apache is going to set later.

You could use this approach to use the error code in PHP:

```
ErrorDocument 400 /error.php?error=400
ErrorDocument 401 /error.php?error=401
...
```

And in PHP test `$_GET["error"]`.

Answer (score 4):

This function is basically a setter/getter *for PHP*'s response code. Without parameters, this function returns the currently set response code *by PHP*. Since the default response code is `200`, without setting a different code by first passing a parameter, `200` will always be returned.

See this example in the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.http-response-code.php):

```
var_dump(http_response_code()); // int(200) - default
http_response_code(404); // set a new code
var_dump(http_response_code()); // int(404) - new code
```

It's also worth noting that `header()` calls may also affect the return value of this function, for example:

```
header('http/1.0 404 not found');
var_dump(http_response_code()); // int(404) - new code
```

Comment: Then what explains how PHP knows which response code is going to get set on my localhost, but not my hosted environment?

Comment: Hard to tell. It might be that in the local build you have some `header()` call before this code is being run.